# Is there a list of SQL execution keywords eg. INSERT, ALTER

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle

I have a program that allows the user to execute SQL scripts. I have a user login to the program but a requirement has come in to prevent any execution even if its an admin user.

What I mean is the user cannot modify tables etc. Normally I would recommend all user connections be setup as read only but there is one element in the program that needs to be able to do an INSERT.

I want to detect the keywords that the user may execute eg/INSERT, UPDATE, ALTER and was hoping there was a defined list somewhere.

Comment: How should Oracle know which statements the user wants to execute?

Comment: It shouldn't I want to prevent the user writing DROP TABLE or INSERT or ALTER or EXEC

Comment: What about UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE and TRUNCATE?

Comment: @Stefan Exactly! More words that needs blacklisting

Comment: isn't this what roles are for? why are u trying to control this by parsing user SQL?  Maybe I'm misunderstanding u tho

Comment: Make the login the "user defined scripts" execute through separate from the login used by the application logic.  The app can then use StoredProcs and/or other control mechanisms to allow/disallow appropriate access.  The "user defined scripts" login can have different access levels, particularly being read only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are better off with a whitelist of things that you want to allow the user to do rather than trying to blacklist everything you do not want them to do.

Are they only allowed to run a SELECT?

Comment: What about this: `SELECT * INTO T1 FROM T;`

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear from your question why you don't just use permissions for this: give users SELECT and/or  INSERT permissions as necessary. You can also wrap critical operations in stored procedures and grant EXECUTE on the procedures only, if that suits your needs better.

Parsing the actual SQL is difficult because you can't just search for certain words, you have to also establish their context. Using 'DELETE' as an example:

```
-- I guess you don't want this
delete from dbo.SomeTable
-- but maybe you do want this?
select * from dbo.SomeTable where Status = 'deleted'
```

And malicious (or just curious) users will certainly have fun testing the limits of your parsing code to see what they can do with EXEC, sp_executesql, OPENQUERY etc.

Permissions (possibly used with stored procedures) are the real solution here, because the alternative you suggest will be a pain to write and maintain and will almost certainly have holes in it.

Comment: This should be the accepted Answer. Much safer and saner than letting user's write SQL code on-the-fly.